# Weird tk Entry box behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am building a simple GUI with multiple entry boxes, check boxes, etc. and came across a very peculiar behavior in the `Tkinter.Entry` class and I'm wondering if anyone else has run into it and/or if I'm just doing something silly.

I created a simple class to wrap each `Tkinter.Entry` object and interface with. I wanted to implement a way to change how wide each box is, so I added a parameter `width` to the class. When I did this, all of my boxes became "linked" and when I type into one box, I typed into every box. before I implemented this functionality it worked fine and when I take it out it works again. Here is my class:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class EntryBox:
    def __init__(self, master, row, column, default_val="", width=20):
        self.val = tk.StringVar()
        self.default_val = default_val
        self.width = width
        # with the width parameter specified
        self.e = tk.Entry(master, text="cb_text", textvariable=self.val, width=self.width)
        # without the width parameter specified (defaults to a width of 20)
        # self.e = tk.Entry(master, text="cb_text", textvariable=self.val)
        self.e.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky=tk.E)
        self.e.insert(0, self.default_val)

    def get_val(self):
        return self.val.get()

    def activate(self):
        self.e.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def deactivate(self):
        self.e.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def focus(self):
        self.e.focus()
```

Here is my program WITHOUT the width parameter included:

[image: Working Program]

Here is my program WITH the width parameter included:

[image: Broken Program]

As you can see, all of the default values filled in to every box and whenever I edit one, I edit all of them.

Here is how I instantiate each object (I don't suspect this to be the issue, but just to be thorough):

```
import Tkinter as tk

ip_addr_box = EntryBox(root, 1, 1, default_val="192.168.201.116")
ip_addr_label = tk.Label(root, text="IP Address").grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.W)
# set up the IP port entry box
ip_port_box = EntryBox(root, 2, 1, default_val="8000")
ip_port_label = tk.Label(root, text="IP port").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=tk.W)
# set up the number of plot points scroll box
# set up the filename entry box
filename_box = EntryBox(root, 4, 1, default_val="log.xlsx")
filename_label = tk.Label(root, text="File Name").grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=tk.W)
# set up how long the test lasts
meas_time_box = EntryBox(root, 3, 4, default_val="5", width=10)
meas_time_label = tk.Label(root, text="Measurement Period")
meas_time_label.grid(row=3, column=5, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)
test_time_box = EntryBox(root, 4, 4, default_val="30", width=10)
test_time_label = tk.Label(root, text="Test Duration").grid(row=4, column=5, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)
```

My guess is that this is a weird bug in Tkinter or something to do with `namespaces` that I don't know enough about.

EDIT: I updated the class code to specify how I don't include the width parameter. I just don't even include it as a named argument when calling `tk.Entry`.

Comment: Just tried again with a more obscure name (`box_width`) and the program still exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the attribute `text='cb_text'`. I don't know what you think that's doing, but `text` is just an abbreviation of `textvariable`, so using it is the same as doing `Entry(..., textvariable='cb_text', textvariable=self.var`, ...).

Apparently there's a bug in how the tkinter Entry widget processes named arguments, and it is triggered when you add the width argument. Every entry widget ends up with the `textvariable` attribute set to `"cb_text"`, meaning they all share the same storage for the value.

Comment: haha, back when I started working with Tkinter I thought I could label Entry widgets like you can with checkboxes. So that's old code left in. Deleting that fixed it! Thank you very much. Teaches me to not leave in old code that didn't seem to do anything!

Answer (score -1):

Inheriting from the Tkinter Entry class works well.  I have slightly manipulated your code.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class EntryBox(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, row, column, default_val="", width=20):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, text="cb_text")
        self.val = tk.StringVar()
        self.default_val = default_val
        self.width = width
        # with the width parameter specified
        # self.e = tk.Entry(master, text="cb_text", textvariable=self.val, width=self.width)
        # without the width parameter specified (defaults to a width of 20)
        # self.e = tk.Entry(master, text="cb_text", textvariable=self.val)
        # self.e.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky=tk.E)
        self.config(textvariable=self.val, width=self.width)
        self.insert(0, self.default_val)
        self.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky=tk.E)


    def get_val(self):
        return self.val.get()

    def activate(self):
        self.e.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def deactivate(self):
        self.e.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def focus(self):
        self.e.focus()
```

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep points to comment directly.

Comment: Just updated the question to clarify. Even if this was an issue (width just defaults to 20), this doesn't explain the odd "all fill together" issue. Also, this should probably be a comment, not an answer.